# How to apply style to parent class, based on nested or deep child having some class?

Tags: css, angular, sass

How can I apply styles to tree Item or li, based on the child-class, using CSS or sass?

```
<li class="tree-item">
      <div class="k-mid">
          <div class="k`enter code here`-in">
          <span class="child-class">test`enter code here`</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please show us your effort so far.

Comment: `li.tree-item:has(selector){}` Is this you are looking for?

Comment: @Jai Yeah I am looking this one only thanks for support